# Call a list of functions recursively in python?

Tags: python, recursion

I have a list of functions called func_list.

I want to execute them one by one, and the result of the execution of `func_list[index]` must be passed as argument to `func_list[index + 1]`, and so on.

I came up with this code:

```
def func(arg, index):
    while index < 10:
        res = func_list[index](arg)
        res = func(res, index+1)
    return res
```

Is there any better way of achieving the same?

Comment: Yes. Use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) is for.

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda a,b: b(a), func_list, FIRST_ARG)
```

This will run

```
func_list[n](func_list[n-1](... func_list[0](FIRST_ARG) ... ))
```

`functools.reduce` takes two arguments (and optionally a third). The first argument is a binary function that returns a value, the second argument is an iterable of values to pass into the binary function, and the optional third is a value to place before that list (as the first argument to the first run of the binary function).

The result of the previous function call is given as `a` to the next function call, along with the next item in the iterable as `b`. Therefore `lambda a,b: b(a)` calls the previous result as the argument of the next function.